# Rank on DataGridView Columns

Tags: c#

I try to set students rank on datagridview columns according their marks and the result is not correct. I try to find my mistake but I could not be able. If someone would help me my code is there. You can see the picture also. [image]

```
int cumulativeRank = 1;
        foreach (IGrouping<object, DataGridViewRow> group in DgvNotes.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().GroupBy(r => r.Cells["ColMoyenne"].Value).OrderByDescending(g => g.Key))
        {
            int rank = cumulativeRank;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in group)
            {
                row.Cells["ColRang"].Value = rank;
                cumulativeRank += 1;
            }
        }
```